# How do I add noise to a raymarched sphere in glsl?

Tags: three.js, glsl, react-three-fiber

I am trying to learn how to apply noise to a sphere that has been raymarched. Similar to how I made this one in shaderpark. : https://shaderpark.com/sculpture/-NjLk2_6yAQON73950oB

I understand the raymarch process just the application of the noise algo to the sphere I become lost on. Below I have an example of a raymarched sphere and the noise algos. Any help where to apply the noise algo is greatly appreciated.

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XlGBW3

https://gist.github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/670c22f3966e662d2f83

I have tried to modify the "p" variable in the GetDist function with a vec3 noise algo but the sphere disappears. What am I missing in the application of noise?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.